# how to build cc_test for android using bazel

Tags: bazel

I am trying to use bazel as build system. 
My project looks like this:

- a static library which contains a bunch of classes and functions
- a dynamic library (so/dll) using the same code as the static library (need to have it because of windows, cc_library rule does not automatically build a dll on windows)
- a cc_test rule which build an executable. it contains unit tests based on google test framework
  It works when running on Windows and Linux. 
  The test rule fails when trying to build Android like this

`bazel build //unit:unit --crosstool_top=@androidndk//:default_crosstool --cpu=armeabi-v7a`

`INFO: Invocation ID: b7c88128-3448-4eb7-bf25-ce8269895956 ERROR: ../yg32wcuz/external/androidndk/BUILD.bazel:39:1: in cc_toolchain_suite rule @androidndk//:toolchain-gnu-libstdcpp: cc_toolchain_suite '@androidndk//:toolchain-gnu-libstdcpp' does not contain a toolchain for cpu 'x64_windows'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//unit:unit' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '@androidndk//:toolchain-gnu-libstdcpp' failed; build aborted`

It looks like that bazel seems to have problem with cc_test and android toolchain

Is there any way to build and run an executable for android using bazel? Maybe I missed some command line arguments

Edit:

tried the solution below and added a sh_test rule but it fails again
using @androidsdk//:adb and leads to the following error

```
ERROR: missing input file '@androidsdk//:platform-tools/adb' 
ERROR: unit/BUILD:61:1: //unit:unit_android: missing input file '@androidsdk//:platform-tools/adb' Target //unit:unit_android failed to build 
ERROR: unit/BUILD:61:1 1 input file(s) do not exist
```

I also need to use $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb to get the adb binary. external/androidsdk/platform-tools/adb does not work. my BUILD file is in a sub folder of the workspace, maybe this is the issue.

removing @androidsdk//:adb fixes this error. there are some adjustments needed in sh_test rule like:

```
sh_test(
    name = "unit_android",
    srcs = ["unit_android.sh"],
    data = [
        ":unit",
        #"@androidsdk//:adb",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@bazel_tools//tools/bash/runfiles", # to access the manifest
    ],
)
```

using runfiles dependency allows me to access the binary via $(rlocation ..) in shell script. but now there seems to be another issue:

when using 'bazel run':
It looks like that bazel is trying to upload the file to msys shell (i am using windows) and not to the device:

```
adb: error: failed to copy '.../_bazel_exb_a/yg32wcuz/execroot/test/bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-fastbuild/bin/unit/unit' to 'C:/Development/msys2/data/local/tmp/unit'
```

when using 'bazel test':
it just states an error and the content of test log is

```
unknown parameter - /users
```

Edit 2:
WORKSPACE file about android sdk/ndk

```
android_ndk_repository(
    name = "androidndk", # Required. Name *must* be "androidndk".
    api_level = 26
)

android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk", # Required. Name *must* be "androidsdk".
    api_level = 26
)
```

In both case I assume env var ANDROID_NDK_HOME (points to ndk), ANDROID_SDK_HOME (points to sdk) and ANDROID_HOME (points to sdk) are set. I also checked the external dir, sdk is in there. Removing "@androidsdk//:adb" seem to work but the bazel shell environment now tries to add a prefix before "/data/local/tmp" and tries to upload to a non existing folder. 
forget about the issue with "/users" (windows path issue ...)

Answer (score 1):

`--crosstool_top` by itself sets both the target and host crosstool, so you may just need to set `--host_crosstool_top` back to the default: `--host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain`

Edit:

Running the test on a device is unfortunately not supported out of the box by `bazel test`. There needs to be some test runner that knows how to put the test on the device, run it, and collect the results. A very simple version of that might look like:

`test.cc`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Test always passes.
  // Return non-zero for test failure.
  return 0;
}
```

`example_android_cc_test.sh`:

```
adb=external/androidsdk/platform-tools/adb

# The test requires a running emulator or connected device.
# The name of the cc_test binary can be passed in using the
# args attribute of sh_test to make this script generic.
$adb push example_test /data/local/tmp

# adb shell returns the exit code of the command
# that was executed, and the exit code of the
# test shell script determines if the sh_test target
# passes or fails.
$adb shell "/data/local/tmp/example_test"
```

`BUILD`:

```
cc_test(
  name = "example_test",
  srcs = ["test.cc"],
  linkopts = ["-pie"],
  linkstatic = 1,
)

sh_test(
  name = "example_android_cc_test",
  srcs = ["example_android_cc_test.sh"],
  data = [
      ":example_test",
      "@androidsdk//:adb",
  ],
)
```

Note that this approach is not hermetic because it relies on an emulator to already be running, or a device to be already connected. It's possible to start an emulator as part of the test, but that's more involved.

Comment: ok, this seems builds a android binary, but: how do I execute the binary on a device?

Comment: You can use `adb` to push the test binary to the device and `adb shell` to run the test. Running the test on a device is unfortunately not supported by `bazel test` out of the box, you'll have to create a test runner for that. I'll update my answer with a very simple version of such a test runner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was assuming to create a shell script that runs adb afterwards. I'll 
try it.

Comment: It fails with setup above ERROR: missing input file '@androidsdk//:platform-tools/adb'
ERROR: unit/BUILD:61:1: //unit:unit_android: missing input file '@androidsdk//:platform-tools/adb'
Target //unit:unit_android failed to build
ERROR: unit/BUILD:61:1 1 input file(s) do not exist

Comment: Do you have an android_sdk_repository rule in your workspace with the name "androidsdk" that points to an Android SDK with the platform tools installed?

Comment: I see now that you're on Windows, I tried this on Linux, so you're correct in your update to your question that you should use the runfiles library instead to get adb

Comment: yes I have a androidsdk rule but I am not specifying any path to sdk rule since I use ANDROID_HOME/ANDROID_SDK_HOME env vars (not sure which one is correct, doc is a bit uncleary about this). Also forget the "/users" option (windows issue with \ and / in directories). The main issue is that bazel tries to copy the file to wrong dir on  the device like C:/Development/msys2/data/local/tmp/unit

Comment: The problem is probably somewhere in `example_android_cc_test.sh`, since I tested that on a linux machine and not on a windows machine. You may need to adjust the script to make it work on windows.

Comment: Also, `android_sdk_repository` reads the ANDROID_HOME environment variable, and android_ndk_repository reads ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable.